# Deformation retraction is non-symmetric.

Tags: algebraic-topology

On page 3 of Allen Hatcher's  [*Algebraic Topology*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Algebraic-Topology-Allen-Hatcher/dp/0521795400), it say that deformation retraction has non-symmetric notion whereas homotopy equivalence is an equivalence relation. It gives the example of a 2-genus torus which deformation retract to three different space, as shown in the below image.

[image]

In the book, it says that any two are not deformation retraction of any other. How can I show this?

Comment: Ah I see. You're asking specifically about the graphs themselves: the three solid black figures, not the torii. Note that you can only deformation retract onto a *subspace*.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Yes that’s true.  But in the book he define deformation retraction between two arbitrary space using mapping cylinder **M_f** defined as the quotient space $X \boxcup Y$ identifing x to f(x). So now Y is a subspace of X. I don’t know am I right or not. Please look into Hatcher’s book.